# Remove Header and Footer from Pandas Dataframe print

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

The following code prints all the values I want but has 
"Date" as the first row and
"Name: Close, Length: 1828, dtype: float64" as the last row

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime

ibm = DataReader('IBM',  'yahoo', datetime(2009,1,1))
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',len(ibm))
print ibm["Close"]
```

How do I print the data w/o this first "Date" line and the last "Name: Close, Length: 1828, dtype:float64" line? Slicing doesn't work, I've tried print ibm["Close"][1:-1] and it just cuts off the 2nd and 2nd to last row.

Comment: When printing to a file it includes them though, I have worked around this by reopening the file and rewriting lines[1:-1] but it would be nice to have a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 17):

```
print ibm["Close"].to_string(header=False)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapetest.py", line 7, in <module>
    print ibm["Close"].to_string(header=False)
TypeError: to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Header'

Comment: Which version of pandas are you running?

Answer (score 1):

That is how a Series object is represented.  You can coerce it to a DataFrame, but you will still have the header.  You can set that to be an empty string, however, and then set the index name to None:

```
df = ibm[['Close']]
df.columns = ['']
df.index.name = None
>>> print(df)
2009-01-02   87.370003
2009-01-05   86.820000
               ...
2016-04-06  150.020004
2016-04-07  148.250000

[1828 rows x 1 columns]
```

If you are going to write it to a file, you don't need to change the column name, just set header to false:

```
df.to_csv(filename, header=False)
```

Comment: what if just show dataframe in python notebook? dont want to write it to disk

Comment: `df.rename(columns={col: "" for col in df})`