# Pandas truncate column names

Tags: pandas

I want to truncate the column headers (only when printing), I am doing properly with the content but not headers.
I am using:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 18)
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the question? Are you asking if the command you have is correct?

Comment: `pd.set_option('max_colwidth',n)` where n is the length of the column name. This will set the length of each columns when you display. display.max_colwidth sets the maximum width of columns. Cells of this length or longer will be truncated with an ellipsis. For documentation, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#frequently-used-options

Comment: updated question, I was talking about column headers not content.

Comment: does this mean the actual value in the column can go beyond the max column width? For ex: If the length of a value in row 1 is 30 but column header width limit is 18, then it should print the column header with max 18 chars and row 1 data of full 30 chars?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490263/remove-header-and-footer-from-pandas-dataframe-print

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 18)` will only trim the contents in the data and not the column header. I think this is a bug or an option that Pandas does not provide. So you have to do this manually. Unfortunately, the solution is not very clean. You can decide to create a function so you can just call that function every time you want to print the dataframe.

If I understand correctly, you want to trim the header of the dataframe columns. Here's an option for you to try.

```
import pandas as pd
c = ['This_Is_A_Long_Name_For_Column_1','This_Is_A_Long_Name_For_Column_2',
     'This_Is_A_Long_Name_For_Column_3','This_Is_A_Long_Name_For_Column_4']
d = [['This is data in row 1 and column 1','This is data in row 1 and column 2',
      'This is data in row 1 and column 3','This is data in row 1 and column 4'],
     ['This is data in row 2 and column 1','This is data in row 2 and column 2',
      'This is data in row 2 and column 3','This is data in row 2 and column 4'],
     ['This is data in row 3 and column 1','This is data in row 3 and column 2',
      'This is data in row 3 and column 3','This is data in row 3 and column 4'],
     ['This is data in row 3 and column 1','This is data in row 4 and column 2',
      'This is data in row 3 and column 3','This is data in row 4 and column 4']]
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)

temp_col_name = df.columns.to_list()

df.rename(columns=lambda x: x[:18], inplace=True) #this will truncate the column name. Then print the dataframe

print (df)

df.columns = temp_col_name #once you are done printing, rename column name back to original

print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
                   This_Is_A_Long_Nam  ...                  This_Is_A_Long_Nam
0  This is data in row 1 and column 1  ...  This is data in row 1 and column 4
1  This is data in row 2 and column 1  ...  This is data in row 2 and column 4
2  This is data in row 3 and column 1  ...  This is data in row 3 and column 4
3  This is data in row 3 and column 1  ...  This is data in row 4 and column 4

[4 rows x 4 columns]
     This_Is_A_Long_Name_For_Column_1  ...    This_Is_A_Long_Name_For_Column_4
0  This is data in row 1 and column 1  ...  This is data in row 1 and column 4
1  This is data in row 2 and column 1  ...  This is data in row 2 and column 4
2  This is data in row 3 and column 1  ...  This is data in row 3 and column 4
3  This is data in row 3 and column 1  ...  This is data in row 4 and column 4

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```